# No skeletal data with RealSense SDK 2.0?

Tags: realsense

Does anyone have info about support for human skeletal data on the SDK 2.0 (or lack thereof)?

The Intel site is oddly silent on the matter.

Would love to know if it's at least in the works. The D400 series cameras look promising.

Answer (score 0):

You could look into [Nuitrack](https://nuitrack.com/) which offers sensor independent tracking.

Note: I'm not affiliated, but I'm also trying to transition from KINECT v2 to RealSense.

Answer (score 0):

To date, Intel does not have any formal plans to release skeletal tracking for the RealSense sensors, though they might provide this via third-party partners in the future.

As @zeFrenchy's answer mentioned, Nuitrack is the only skeleton tracking middleware available for the RealSense at the moment.

(If you want to know for sure, you'll have to find a contact at Intel.)

---

As for official online sources, here are some hints from Intel Customer support.

March 2018 - [GitHub librealsense issue #1376](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/1376)

> The RealSense SDK 2.0 is focused on providing depth across multiple
>   operating systems and wrapper. All open source. We provide a few code
>   samples which we hope the community will add to. We also provide tools
>   like the viewer. What we are hoping to do is expand into middleware
>   like person tracking or scanning via third-party partners. Please
>   watch our site as we bring these partners on board.

Oct 2017 - [GitHub librealsense issue #743](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/743)

> We cannot comment on development roadmaps at the moment but please
>   provide more details on your use case and requirements are so that we
>   may scope this feature for the communities needs.